# Powershell script executable self destruct?

Tags: powershell

I am converting a .ps1 script to an exe using PS2EXE. After running the executable, I would like it to delete itself. I have tried to use, "-LiteralPath" and "$PSScriptRoot" but both return null during runtime as an executable.

Any responses are appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Is the conversion to an executable mandatory? You can delete the script file with `Remove-Item` from within the script file itself.

Comment: It is mandatory

Answer (score 0):

In your code...

1. On your executable launch, create a scheduled task (to execute remove-item) to
   launch when an event is logged. Either using an existing event log, or [create your own](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/use-powershell-to-create-and-to-use-a-new-event-log/#:%7E:text=%20Use%20PowerShell%20to%20Create%20and%20to%20Use,I%20notice%20when%20I%20check%20the...%20More%20).
2. In your scheduled task, you assign your own code that you will write
   to the event log.
3. In your code, on complete, you [write to the event log](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/how-to-use-powershell-to-write-to-event-logs).
4. The task should fire when you write to the log.

... or in your code, create a scheduled task (remove-item) as the last action in your code, to execute, say, 1 minute after being created.

Update as per my follow-up comment to you regarding the path issue you seem to be having.

> "Can you provide an example for this? The path must be its current
> location, which may be unknown when it is being executed."

Tested - Example Code that gets converted to an executable usin PS2EXE.

Note:
Reports have been circulating that AV solutions are now alerting on this type of conversion ps1 to exe use cases.

Powershell script hello.ps1 converted to exe

```
# Get executable process path
$ExecutablePath = (Get-Process -ProcessName hello).path

# Check for an existing task
Function Remove-ExecutableTask
{
    Try   
    {
        Get-ScheduledTask -TaskName 'RemoveCurrentExecutable' -ErrorAction Stop
        Unregister-ScheduledTask -TaskName RemoveCurrentExecutable -Confirm:$false
    }  
    Catch {$PSItem.Exception.Message}
}

# Create Scheduled task
Function New-ExecutableTask
{
    $ExecutableAction = $(New-ScheduledTaskAction -Execute 'Powershell.exe' -Argument "-NoProfile -command & {Remove-Item -Path $ExecutablePath}")
    $Trigger          = New-ScheduledTaskTrigger -Once -At $("{0:hhtt}" -f (get-date).AddHours(1))
    Register-ScheduledTask -Action $ExecutableAction -Trigger $Trigger -TaskName 'RemoveCurrentExecutable' -Description 'Remove the target executable.'
}


Remove-ExecutableTask
New-ExecutableTask

'Hello World!'
"Hello World ran from: $ExecutablePath"

# Test run from the PowerShell consolehost and Results
<#
 Try{(Get-ChildItem -Path 'D:\temp\hello.exe' -ErrorAction Stop).FullName;&{D:\temp\hello.exe}}Catch{$PSItem.Exception.Message}
Cannot find path 'D:\temp\hello.exe' because it does not exist.

 Try{Get-ScheduledTask -TaskName 'RemoveCurrentExecutable' -ErrorAction Stop}Catch{$PSItem.Exception.Message}
No MSFT_ScheduledTask objects found with property 'TaskName' equal to 'RemoveCurrentExecutable'.  Verify the value of the property and retry.

 # Convert the script using PS2EXE and execute it

 Try{(Get-ChildItem -Path 'D:\temp\hello.exe' -ErrorAction Stop).FullName;&{D:\temp\hello.exe}}Catch{$PSItem.Exception.Message}
D:\temp\hello.exe

 Try{Get-ScheduledTask -TaskName 'RemoveCurrentExecutable' -ErrorAction Stop}Catch{$PSItem.Exception.Message}

TaskPath                                       TaskName                          State     
--------                                       --------                          -----     
\                                              RemoveCurrentExecutable           Ready     

(Get-ChildItem -Path D:\Temp\hello.exe).FullName
D:\Temp\hello.exe

 # Execute the scheduled task

 Start-ScheduledTask -TaskName RemoveCurrentExecutable

 Try{(Get-ChildItem -Path 'D:\temp\hello.exe' -ErrorAction Stop).FullName;&{D:\temp\hello.exe}}Catch{$PSItem.Exception.Message}
Cannot find path 'D:\temp\hello.exe' because it does not exist.
#>
```

Of course I just manually started the script, but it would execute on the time defined.

Comment: You require a path to use remove-item, that's what I originally tried to do but path = null during executable runtime.

Comment: My suggestion allows for a path. That task is outside the scope/execution of the executable, not in it. The remove-item in the task properties, your code just sets the task. Your code, does whatever it needs to do, and at the end sets a task, then your executable closes. At some later time you defined, your task runs to remove your executable from the path you define. A filesystem item cannot be deleted until all WIndows filesystem handles are released and that can take several seconds or more depending on where the code had run.

Comment: Can you provide an example for this? The path must be its current location, which may be unknown when it is being executed.

Comment: In your code, you'd just trap the path that your script is running from. Say at the top of your code, just use, `(Get-Process -ProcessName HelloWorld).path` and pass the proper console PowerShell command with Remove-Item and that path string to the new scheduled task creation step.